# Decrypt file have bad data if wrong key

Tags: c#, encryption, des

I've code to decrypt file in DES Encryption, I try I keep getting the file even though I enter the key at the time when the key decrypt the encrypted differently. But i've get the error.

```
 while ((data = cryptostreamDecr.ReadByte()) != -1)  // Message Error : Bad Data.
```

Which code should I add or change in order to keep the process running decrypt?

```
private static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sKey)
{
    var DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    DES.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
     using (var fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,
                    desdecrypt,
                    CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    int data;

                    fsread.Flush();

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        while ((data = cryptostreamDecr.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        {
                            ms.WriteByte((byte)data);
                        }

                        cryptostreamDecr.Close();

                        using (var fsWrite = new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Truncate))
                        {
                            ms.WriteTo(fsWrite);
                            ms.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Encrypt Code :

```
public static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sKey)
        {
            FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
               FileMode.Open,
               FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
            ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsInput,
               desencrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
            fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            fsInput.SetLength(0);
            cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cryptostream.Close();
            fsInput.Close();
        }
```

**[EDIT]** : remove in Encypt :

> cryptostream.FlushFinalBlock();

And add in decrypt

> DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64 bits is the only valid key size for the DES encryption algorithm.
8 bits is equal to one ASCII character means 64 bits is equal to 8 Characters.

If you send 8 characters only then check this ([C# "Bad Data" exception when decrypting encrypted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591361/c-sharp-bad-data-exception-when-decrypting-encrypted-file)). It may solve your problem.

**[Edit]**
Add `DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;` in `DecryptFile`.

Comment: yes, I do use 8 characters, I mean if I try to insert key in the decryption process is different from when my encryption I get his error: bad data.

Comment: i not used output destination file in decrypt parameter, if you mean that the problem ?

Comment: I've done it. But same error in same line. I have posted my ecrypt code.

Comment: Add `DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;` in `DecryptFile`.

Comment: it's work. thanks. But have new problem. The file can't open when decrypt if enter the same key while in encrypt key. Do you know where the problem?